# Problem with \input{file} printing text on a new page

Tags: input

I have 5 exercise files and the final paragraph of Exercise_1.tex (which I inserted into the main file using \include{Exercise_1} happens to end at the top of a new page. Therefore, I wanted to use \input{Exercise_2} to append exercise 2 at the end of exercise 1 but is not working at all. As much as I try, the content of Exercise_2.tex continues to appear at a new page. What is causing this to happen? I would really appreciate your help.

The code of my main.tex is given as:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, style=ieee]{biblatex}

\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} 


\usepackage{hyperref}


\hypersetup{

colorlinks=true,

linkcolor=black,

filecolor=magenta,

urlcolor=blue,

pdftitle={Assignment},

pdfpagemode=UseNone,

citecolor=black,

}


\title{Assignmen}

\author{me}

\date{\today} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\include{Exercise_1}

\input{Exercise_2}

\include{Exercise_3}

\newgeometry{top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm}

\begin{landscape}

\include{Exercise_4}

\end{landscape}

\restoregeometry

\include{Exercise_5}

\include{Exercise_6}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've found out right now that if I write \input{Exercise_2} at the bottom of Exercise_1.tex, it works! But why does it work if I write it within the Exercise_1.tex and not if I write \input{Exercise_2} after \include{Exercise_1} in my main.tex file as I have it above in the main post?

Comment: Don't use \include, use \input instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for your reply, do you mean to use \input on Exercise_1? And what od I do for the exercise not to appear in the title page? Simply use a \newpage? Is this something common  that happens when using \input?

Comment: \include will use a \clearpage at the begin and the end. So it is only suitable for text where the page breaks are wanted. In all other cases use \input and issue the \newpage/clearpage yourself.